# How Can I Apply Conditional Decorator to a Command Handler with SimpleInjector?

Tags: c#, .net, simple-injector

I have the following command handler interface:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

I am decorating instances of this interface with the following concrete class:

```
public class ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
     public ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator(
         IValidator<TCommand> validator, 
         ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler)
     {
     }

     public void Handle(TCommand command) {  }        
}
```

BUT.... I don't necessarily want to decorate ALL command handlers and only want to decorate the `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` IF an instance exists/is registered of `IValidator<TCommand>` for the concrete type of TCommand. Note that the `IValidator<TCommand>` instance is injected in the constructor of the decorator class.

For example, if I have a command handler:

```
public class CreateFooCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateFooCommand>
```

I only want to decorate if I have the following instance registered:

```
public class CreateFooCommandValidator : IValidator<CreateFooCommand>
```

If the `CreateFooCommandValidator` does not exist then I don't want to decorate the `CreateFooCommandHandler` with the `ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator`.

I am using the following when registering with SimpleInjector:

```
var container = new Container();

container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), assemblies);
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies);
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    typeof(ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<>));
```

Obviously this fails if there is not instance of `IValidator<>` present for any given `ICommandHandler<>`. For info `assemblies` is a collection of assemblies used in for registering generic classes.

What should I use to register the decorator/validators to achieve what I want to do, if at all that is possible? I don't want to switch from using SimpleInjector.

Furthermore, if it is possible, is this recommended or is it a violation of SOLID principles, or even just a code smell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a conditional decorator by analysing registrations in the container and deciding whether to decorate each instance or not but I don't think it's the best option. The simplest solution is to define and register a fallback `NullValidator` for those instances where an actual `IValidator` does not exist ...

```
public class NullValidator<TCommand> : IValidator<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Validate(TCommand command)
    {
    }
}
```

Registered as a *Conditional*:

```
var container = new Container();

container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), assemblies);
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies);
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IValidator<>), 
    typeof(NullValidator<>), 
    c => !c.Handled);
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    typeof(ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<>));

container.Verify();
```

> I don't want to switch from using SimpleInjector.

Good man!

> Furthermore, if it is possible, is this recommended or is it a violation of SOLID principles, or even just a code smell?

This is exactly the kind of thing `RegisterConditional` exists for :-)

Comment: Nice simple solution.

Comment: An alternative solution is to register the validators as collection (optionally wrapped in a composite).

Comment: I always use this conditional solution, nice, quick and clean. :-)